# Issue with "group by" and "having"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

```
SELECT *
FROM RF_CustomerCard
WHERE DateOfBirth IN (
    SELECT DateOfBirth
    FROM RF_CustomerCard 
    HAVING COUNT(DateOfBirth) > 1 
    GROUP BY DateOfBirth
)
```

SQL Server 2019 is saying I have a syntax error by "GROUP"

I am trying to find employees who have the same date of birth

Comment: Um, `group by` comes before `having`?

Comment: Group by comes before having

Comment: By the way you can do this with a window function also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [D. Use a GROUP BY clause with a HAVING clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-use-a-group-by-clause-with-a-having-clause) from Microsofts's [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-use-a-group-by-clause-with-a-having-clause) shows `HAVING` comes after `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM RF_CustomerCard
WHERE DateOfBirth IN (
    SELECT DateOfBirth
    FROM RF_CustomerCard 
    GROUP BY DateOfBirth
    HAVING COUNT(DateOfBirth) > 1 
)
ORDER BY DateOfBirth -- Optional
```